# Rspec static_pages_spec.rb fail, can't see title or H1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When running following command:

> bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

i get following errors

```
 FF.......

    Failures:

      1) Static pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
         Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sample App')
           expected css "h1" with text "Sample App" to return something
         # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

      2) Static pages Home page should have the base title
         Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title',
           expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" to return something
         # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

    Finished in 0.38131 seconds
    9 examples, 2 failures

    Failed examples:

    rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:4 # Static pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
    rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8 # Static pages Home page should have the base title
```

my static_pages_spec.rb looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Static pages" do
  describe "Home page" do
    it "should have the h1 'Sample App'" do
      visit root_path
      page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sample App')
    end
    it "should have the base title" do
      visit root_path
      page.should have_selector('title',
                        text: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App")
    end
    it "should not have a custom page title" do
      visit root_path
      page.should_not have_selector('title', text: '| Home')
    end
  end
describe "Help page" do
    it "should have the h1 'Help me'" do
        visit help_path
        page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Help me')
    end
it "should have the title 'Help me'" do
  visit help_path
   page.should have_selector('title',
                text: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help me")
end
end
describe "About page" do
  it "should have the h1 'About us'" do
    visit about_path
    page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'About us')
  end
it "should have the title 'About us'" do
  visit about_path
  page.should have_selector('title',
                text: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About us")
    end
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
  it "should have the h1 'Contact'" do
    visit contact_path
    page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Contact')
  end

it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
  visit contact_path
  page.should have_selector('title',
                text: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
    end
  end
end
```

my routes.rb

```
   SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
      root to: 'static_pages#home'

      match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
      match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
      match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

I had 9/9 failures before, but then I added

> config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

to the spec/rspec_helper.rb, and now i'm left with the to failures above

Comment: What is the h1 and title of the page being generated?

Comment: I can't see that, my page is giving me following:
_Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/static_pages"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes._

and rake routes is showing

_   root  /                  static_pages#home
   help  /help(.:format)    static_pages#help
  about  /about(.:format)   static_pages#about
contact  /contact(.:format) static_pages#contact_

Comment: Please add your view code for 'static_pages#home'

Comment: I like to add a test like this since the failure output will show me what is actually showing up in the view: it { should have_content("xxxxxxxx") }

Comment: @jesseWolgamott

<div class="center hero-unit">
 <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

 <h2>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
 </h2>

 <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>

<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>

Comment: I used your code, with your specs, and it worked perfectly without error. If you'll post to github, I'll take a look there.

Comment: https://github.com/kwadwoadu/sample_app

Comment: I tried 1000 things, not sure what the trick was, but it's working now! Thanks a lot @JesseWolgamott !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete your public/index.html file. Once removed, your code runs fine.

A way to check what's going on:

1. Add `gem "launchy"` to your Gemfile
2. bundle
3. add
   `save_and_open_page` after your visit root_path

Comment: I didn't see your answer until now, but that was one of the things i did, might have been deleting the index.html that did some magic!